# How to return to beginning of loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, input

```
search_room = raw_input("Search the:")

if search_room == "classroom":
    print "You quitly make your way to the classroom, which is empty besides last night's homework"
    sleep(3)
    print "Enter 'inspect' into the command line to inspect the homework, or enter exit, to return to the kitchen."
    action = raw_input("Command:")

    if action == "inspect":
        print "Hmph, uncompleted. Thats strange."
        print "Enter 'inspect' into the command line to inspect the homework, or enter exit, to return to the kitchen."
        action = raw_input("Command:")
    if action == "exit":
        print "you return to the kitchen"
        search_room = raw_input("Search the:")
        if action == "classroom":
```

I'm trying to figure out how to have this loop so i one could travel back and forth between the kitchen and the classroom, but if I try to go back to the classroom after exiting, I get an error message regarding a later 'for loop'.

Comment: ... There's no loop here...

Comment: Is this code meant to go inside of a loop?

Comment: In general, it looks like you probably want to read up on the concept of a Finite State Machine.

Comment: Downvote for no actual sense.

Comment: Sharth - why did you edit indentation and delete 'Thanks'?

Comment: Also, in python, to go skip everything else in the loop and go back to the beginning, you want [the continue statement](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Comment: How might i implement a 'continue' statement? Thanks - I'm sorry i mislabeled the post, as you can tell, I'm very new.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your trying to figure out how to set up a loop that will let you go from kitchen back to classroom and so on and so forth without needing to nest an infinite amount of conditionals. I suggest you have an outer `while(true)` loop power the sequence of steps, and add conditions to check if a move is valid (to go to to the kitchen you must currently be in the classroom and have entered exit, ect)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the code block inside its own loop with a simple boolean sentinel value (`while not stop`) and if stop is set to true at any point, the otherwise endless loop will stop. Also remember the importance of python indentations for distinguishing code scopes, different from languages like java where it doesn't matter where you put the code as long as it is between the { }. Also consecutive if statements will each be executed individually unless you use if..elif which is what I think you want because you are comparing the same variable in the same scope.

Also if you have more than two rooms, like something in the game Clue, you should define some sort of scoping for each room. If you are in a room, which rooms can you access from there? I did this just with a simple dictionary `scopes` where each room is associated with a list of rooms it can access which is verified on getting `search_room`. They only have access to each other right now, but you can add more to each list to increase scope to other rooms (and add more `if` branches)

```
stop = false;
scopes = {"kitchen": ["classroom"], "classroom": ["kitchen"]}
locCur = "kitchen" #starting room
locPrev = "kitchen"
while not stop:
    search_room = raw_input("Search the:")
    if scopes[locCur].index(search_room) > -1 : #validate the room choice
        if search_room == "classroom":
            locCur = "classroom" #update current scope
            print "You quietly make your way to the classroom, which is empty besides last night's homework"
            sleep(3)
            print "Enter 'inspect' into the command line to inspect the homework, or enter exit, to   return to the kitchen."
            action = raw_input("Command:")
            if action == "inspect":
                print "Hmph, uncompleted. Thats strange."
                print "Enter 'inspect' into the command line to inspect the homework, or enter exit, to return to the kitchen."
                action = raw_input("Command:")
                if action == "inspect":
                    #print/do something else
            elif action == "exit":
                locCur = locPrev #set scope back to what it was
                print "you return to the " + locPrev
                locPrev = "classroom" #store this location
                continue
        elif search_room == "kitchen":
            #do something for this room
            print "message"
            continue
        elif search_room == "some other room":
            #do something for this room
            continue
        elif search_room == "stop":
            stop = true
```